# Is this a JavaScript constructor pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I've been using this pattern in my JS code:

```
function Thing() {
    var otherData = {
        // Private variables?
        name : "something"
    }

    var myThing = {
        data: "somedata",
        someFunction: function () {
        console.log(otherData.name);
        }
    }

    return myThing;
}
```

Then when using it doing:

```
var thing = Thing();
thing.someFunction();
```

I've seen examples of constructors and singletons in JS, but I haven't run across this pattern before. Is there a name for this pattern? Are there any potential problems with this pattern? Previously I was just using the object literal pattern, but wanted to get private-ish variables by putting it in a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a name for this pattern?

That has various names. The common ones I've heard for it are:

- *factory function*
- *maker function* (this is the term Douglas Crockford, who popularized them, uses)
- *builder function*

To avoid confusion we don't call them "constructor functions" or "constructors" as that term is specifically for functions used with `new`, which yours isn't.

*(Note: "builder function" in this context is not related to the builder **pattern** [e.g., GoF patterns]. That's a completely different thing. Similarly, "factory function" here isn't really related to the factory pattern, but in this case there's overlap, as the factory pattern uses factory functions. "Maker" has the advantage of not having that potential confusion; I'm sure there's some "maker pattern" somewhere, but at least not in the initial GoF book.)*

> Are there any potential problems with this pattern?

Well, there are potential problems with all patterns. :-) There's nothing particularly problematic with this one, though, no.

Just to point out one problem it *doesn't* have: Someone might mention that you aren't leveraging prototypes with that pattern, but perhaps you just don't need one with that particular builder, and if you did, you could easily use one:

```
var thingProto = {
    method: function() {
        // I'm a shared method
    }
};
function buildThing() {
    var otherData = {
        // Private variables?
        name : "something"
    }

    var myThing = Object.create(thingProto);
    myThing.data = "somedata";
    myThing.someFunction = function () {
        console.log(otherData.name);
    };

    return myThing;
}
```

Doesn't change the pattern.

---

As a style note, normally you wouldn't capitalize it, as the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that a capitalized function is a *constructor function*. So `Thing` might be called `createThing` or `buildThing` or just `thing`.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor invocation pattern is when you prefix a function call with the `new` keyword followed by a space. This allows the function to act as a constructor, assigning its prototype property (`ConstructorFunction.prototype`) as the prototype attribute (`instanceObj.__proto__`) of the returned object, and modifying the object's properties through the `this` keyword. Therefore, the way you're using that function is not a "constructor pattern".

The encapsulation of data using function closures is commonly referred to as the [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

Here is the relevant section from Addy Osmani's book: [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

> The Module pattern was originally defined as a way to provide both
>   private and public encapsulation for classes in conventional software
>   engineering.
>
> In JavaScript, the Module pattern is used to further emulate the
>   concept of classes in such a way that we're able to include both
>   public/private methods and variables inside a single object, thus
>   shielding particular parts from the global scope. What this results in
>   is a reduction in the likelihood of our function names conflicting
>   with other functions defined in additional scripts on the page.
>
> Privacy
>
> The Module pattern encapsulates "privacy", state and organization
>   using closures. It provides a way of wrapping a mix of public and
>   private methods and variables, protecting pieces from leaking into the
>   global scope and accidentally colliding with another developer's
>   interface. With this pattern, only a public API is returned, keeping
>   everything else within the closure private.
>
> This gives us a clean solution for shielding logic doing the heavy
>   lifting whilst only exposing an interface we wish other parts of our
>   application to use. The pattern is quite similar to an
>   immediately-invoked functional expression (IIFE - see the section on
>   namespacing patterns for more on this) except that an object is
>   returned rather than a function.
>
> It should be noted that there isn't really an explicitly true sense of
>   "privacy" inside JavaScript because unlike some traditional languages,
>   it doesn't have access modifiers. Variables can't technically be
>   declared as being public nor private and so we use function scope to
>   simulate this concept. Within the Module pattern, variables or methods
>   declared are only available inside the module itself thanks to
>   closure. Variables or methods defined within the returning object
>   however are available to everyone.

Comment: This isn't really the module pattern. Yes, it uses the same underlying technology (closures), but the module pattern is about bigger pieces than the OP's builder. Modules, to be precise. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't understand why the size of his function should dictate whether or not it's the module pattern. He said "Previously I was just using the object literal pattern, but wanted to get private-ish variables by putting it in a closure." That sounds like the module pattern to me.

Comment: It's not the size of the function, it's the intent and use of it. When you talk about the "module pattern," you're implying you're talking about modules, not instances. That's why we have the term builder or factory function, for when we're talking about something with a different use case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The builder pattern refers to something entirely different in every source I've read. It's used to reduce the complexity of constructing objects with several dynamic options and attributes. While I could see how the factory pattern applies here, the factory pattern is about decoupling the user code from the actual constructor(s) used through a factory interface, allowing for polymorphic method dispatch and usage of the created objects through the defined interface. Notice how it has nothing to do with privacy/encapsulation through closures, which is the module pattern.

Comment: I didn't say builder **pattern**. I said builder **function**. Yes, there's a huge difference between those two things. Similarly I didn't say factory pattern, either, though yes, factory functions are part of implementing it. I'll call out that I'm not talking about the pattern in my answer, in case someone else gets confused by it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If builder/factory function means a function that creates an object, then returns it, then I agree that you are correct; this is an example of that.. However, since the question asked specifically about getting "private-ish variables by putting it in a closure", then I believe that concept refers to the module pattern. I'm sorry for thinking wrongly that you were referring to the builder and factory patterns. It's just that I have never heard of the terms "builder function" and "factory function" so I have no idea what they're supposed to mean.

Comment: Both are fairly common in JS circles. I just remembered the other one that's been nagging at me. I kept thinking "There's another common term for this. It's not 'creator', obviously not constructor...what is it?! Argh!" Answer: *Maker* functions. That's the name Crockford uses. :-)